# jQuery .val appears to be poorly defined in closure compiler

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure-compiler

I noticed that the closure compiler will not accept number as a type for the first parameter of `.val`, yet the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value) states it does.  Looking at my jQuery extern file, it has:

```
/**
 * @param {(string|Array<string>|function(number,*))=} arg1
 * @return {(string|number|Array<string>|!jQuery)}
 */
jQuery.prototype.val = function(arg1) {};
```

The parameter does not seem to match up with the documentation for `.val`.  I'd like to get the extern file aligned with the documentation, but was wondering if jQuery accepts more types than are documented, or something else obvious that I am missing.

Comment: So modify it to accept a number.

Comment: .val() sets the value of the value property on input elements. There are only so many input element types, and each one accepts a certain type of value. It should be relatively easy to figure out what types you should expect .val() to support using that knowledge.

Comment: @KevinB Clearly, I can redefine it to match the documentation.  My question was really, given that extern file is in about the dozenth revision, with 700+ open issues, none of which involves .val, I am trying to figure out if there is some reason why it is defined that way before I change something fairly basic in the extern file.

Comment: jQuery documentation has historically been lacking. If the documentation now specifies numbers as a valid parameter type, a pull request to fix the extern would be welcome.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth Thanks, Chad.  I'll take a look at jQuery first to make sure I know what it's thinking, and do that.